# Wireshark/Winpcap Filter ICMPv6 Router Advertisement

Tags: wireshark, winpcap

What is the filter expression syntax on wireshark or winpcap to only display icmpv6 router advertisement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Type in filter:

```
icmpv6.type == 134
```

Answer (score 11):

**Use Wireshark filters with these codes to filter out what you need respectively**

neighbor advertisement:

> icmpv6.type == 136

neighbour solicitation:

> icmpv6.type == 135

router solicitation:

> icmpv6.type == 133

router advertisement:

> icmpv6.type == 134

Redirect:

> icmpv6.type == 137